# Subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 23000 rows and 8 columns

I want to subset it using only unique identifiers that are in column 1. I do this by,

```
total_res2 <- unique(total_res['Entrez.ID']);
```

This produces 17,000 rows with only the information from column 1.

I am wondering how to extract the unique rows, based on this column and also take the information from the other 7 columns using only these unique rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the rows of `total_res` containing the first occurrences of each `Entrez.ID` value:

```
subset(total_res, ! duplicated( Entrez.ID ) )
```

or did you mean you only want rows whose `Entrez.ID` is not duplicated:

```
subset(total_res, ave(seq_along(Entrez.ID), Entrez.ID, FUN = length) == 1 )
```

Next time please provide test data and expected output.